What is the Recamán constant?
If you look up the Recamán constant, you probably won't find anything. It's sort of a name I just made up to represent a fundamental number in the Recamán sequence.
For those of you who don't know, the Recamán sequence goes like this:

"Recamán's sequence (or Recaman's sequence): a(0) = 0; for n > 0, a(n) = a(n-1) - n if nonnegative and not already in the sequence, otherwise a(n) = a(n-1) + n."*

Don't worry if it takes a bit to understand what that means. There's also a helpful Numberphile video on the Recamán's sequence: The Slightly Spooky Recamán Sequence - Numberphile
Here is how I define the Recamán constant: Consider all of the numbers in the Recamán sequence up to k. Now consider all of the sets of numbers from the first term in the Recamán sequence, 0, up to the nth term, where n is a number between 1 and k (inclusive). In each of these subsets, take the largest number in that subset and divide it by n; let's call this number c. Now add the value of c for each of these subsets and divide it by k; in other words, you're finding the average of c. Let's call this new number r. I define the Recamán constant to be what r approaches as k grows without bound.
It'll help to understand what I mean if we go through a few examples.
Let's start with k = 1. Here the only subset you have is 0. And since 0/1 = 0, here r=0.
Next let's go to k = 2. The first 2 terms of the Recamán sequence are 0 and 1. For the first subset you have 0/1 = 0, and in the second subset you have 1/2 = 1/2. You take their average which is 1/4. So here r = 1/4.
Next let's go to k = 3. The first 3 terms of the Recamán sequence are 0, 1, and 3. For the first subset you have 0/1 = 0, in the second subset you have 1/2 = 1/2, and in the third subset you have 3/3 = 1. You take their average which is 1/2. So here r = 1/2.
Next let's go to k = 4. The first 4 terms of the Recamán sequence are 0, 1, 3, and 6. For the first subset you have 0/1 = 0, the second subset you have 1/2 = 1/2, the third subset you have 3/3 = 1, and the fourth subset you have 6/4 = 3/2. You take their average which is 3/4. So here r = 3/4.
Next let's go to k = 5. The 1st 5 terms of the Recamán sequence are 0, 1, 3, 6, and 2. For the first subset you have 0/1 = 0, the second subset you have 1/2 = 1/2, the third subset you have 3/3 = 1, the fourth subset you have 6/4 = 3/2, and the fifth subset you have 2/5 = 2/5. You take their average which is 17/25. So here r = 17/25.
Next let's go to k = 6. The 1st 6 terms of the Recamán sequence are 0, 1, 3, 6, 2, and 7. For the 1st subset you have 0/1 = 0, the 2nd subset you have 1/2 = 1/2, the 3rd subset you have 3/3 = 1, the 4th subset you have 6/4 = 3/2, the 5th subset you have 6/5 = 6/5, and the 6th subset you have 7/6 = 7/6. You take their average which is 161/180. So here r = 161/180, approximately 0.894444.
I don't actually know for sure whether or not r converges. It might cycle, behave chaotically, or diverge to infinity. I'd like to see a proof of the result, not just an answer. I'd also be interested in seeing partial answers with proofs; that is, a proof that r converges (if it does) or a lower or upper bound for the Recamán constant.
*OEIS A005132

The OEIS page links to a table of the first $100000$ terms in the sequence, so you can test your limit pretty far.

Thanks. I'll try writing a Matlab program or something to do most of the work for me.

While I'm at it I might as well code up a program that generates the Recaman Sequence.

Sure.  I suppose basic properties are known...like, does every natural number appear in the sequence?  If not, what is the sequence of missing entries?  I assume, for instance, that $\sum \frac 1{a_n}$ diverges, for example, but even that is worth a proof.
